# How to check which architecture device is using

Tags: android

I'm using a library which doesn't support `armv6` architecture. I want to show users a toast if `armv6` architecture is detected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this class: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html

Method:

```
public static String getProperty (String propertyName)
```

If think `os.arch` property is what you're looking for.

```
Log.i("mytag", "os.arch: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("armv6")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Using armv6!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple.

```
   if (System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("armv6")) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "armv6", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
```